# Spacelike separation, special case

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, terminology

This is merely a terminology question. Consider two events A and B. Now suppose A and B happen in two different black holes, i.e. there is no way from A to B (or B to A). Is this fundamentally different from a "normal" spacelike separation, where the finite lightspeed hinders to get from A to B? (It does also in the black hole case...)
(Context: Trying to abuse physical notions for describing problem chess; repetition of position would correspond to a closed timelike curve)

Comment: Re, "...where finite light speed hinders to get from A to B." Nothing moves in spacetime. If A and B are _events_ in a spacetime diagram, then there is nothing that "gets" from either one to the other. But if A is a flash of light, and B is a point on the world-line of some observer, then under normal conditions (e.g., not in the neighborhood of any black hole) there will be other points on the observer's world line that lie within the future light cone of the event A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GR we don't have displacement vectors (except for infinitesimal displacements). So we can't say, as in SR, that the vector from A to B is spacelike. There can also be things in GR like events that can be connected either by a purely timelike, future-directed curve or by a purely spacelike curve. To describe your situation, what we would typically say is that A is not inside the light cone of B.

Comment: No vectors? I should nail me a poster to the wall: "Don't rely on intuition when it comes to SR/GR/QM!" :-) THX for clarifying the terminology for me.